# Count query is taking too long - over 24 hours have passed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok, most possibly I am doing something wrong, but following the advice of a user here I run this query:

```
SELECT id, item, 
   (SELECT COUNT(item) FROM Table1 WHERE id=a.id AND item=a.item) cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.id,b.item FROM Table1 a, Table1 b) a
ORDER BY id, item;
```

on this table:

```
ID         ITEM
-----------------
0001        345
0001        345
0001        120
0002        567
0002        034
0002        567
0003        567
0004        533
0004        008
...
```

in order to get this result:

```
ID  ITEM    CNT
1   8       0
1   34      0
1   120     1
1   345     2
1   533     0
1   567     0
2   8       0
2   34      1
...
```

but it is taking too long and the query is still running after a day...
Is there a way to improve performance? I have about 4 million rows

Thank you

Comment: Have you added indexes and keys?

Comment: The query you're running in your FROM clause is hammering the database! You're joining the tables with no where condition, so it's essentially doing a cross join of every record, and when there's 4 million records that will take a VERY long time!

Comment: I am sorry I am new to mysql so I'm not sure what this is - so the answer is no..can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You're telling the database to check 4 million rows against 4 million rows. Which means it has to do (4,000,000 * 4,000,000) = 16,000,000,000,000 calculations. Not including the other calculations you have it doing.

Comment: Please stop usimg MYSQL untill You will learn basics....

Comment: Once you have implemented Gordon's answer, please add a comment under it telling us how fast the query runs now ;-) And Avitus' remark about indices still applies.

Comment: Do you want to take each combination of ID and Item and count that?  So even though there is no ID 1 with an Item of 8 you report the zero.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, cross joins are bad and you should avoid them at all costs. In this case though, he needs a cross join for the desired result (though it can be implemented better - see Gordon's answer). This makes the answer a little more complicated than just the basics, so no need to be rude about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is quite convoluted.  I think you just want to count the combinations of `id` and `item`.  If so, this is a simple aggregation:

```
select id, item, count(*)
from Table1 a
group by id, item;
```

If you want all ids and items to appear, then use a driver table:

```
select driver.id, driver.item, coalesce(count(t1.id), 0)
from (select id.id, item.item
      from (select distinct id from Table1) id cross join
           (select distinct item from Table1) item
     ) driver left outer join
     Table1 t1
     on driver.id = t1.id and driver.item = t1.item
group by driver.id, driver.item;
```

The original query has this statement:

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT a.id,b.item FROM Table1 a, Table1 b) a
```

This is doing full cartesian product and then doing a distinct.  So, if your table has 100,000 rows, then the intermediate table has 10,000,000,000 rows for the distinct (I don't think MySQL optimizes this a bit better).  Doing the distinct first (as for the driver) greatly reduces the volume of data.

EDIT:

There are a class of SQL questions where you need to look at all combinations of two or more items and then determine values for everyone (even those that don't exist in the data) or find those that are *not* in the data.  These problems pose the same problem:  how do you get information about values not in the data?

The solution that I advocate is to create a table that has all possible combinations, and then use `left [outer] join` for the remaining tables.  I call this the "driver" table, because the rows in this query "drive" the query by defining the population for subsequent joins.

This terminology is fairly consistent with the reference in the comment.  The comment is using the term from the optimizer perspective.  Some join algorithms -- particularly nested loop and index lookup -- treat the two sides of the join differently; for these, one side is the "driving/driver" table.  For instance, when joining from a large table to a small reference table, the large table is the driving table and the other table is accessed through an index.  Other join algorithms -- such as merge join and hash joins (in general) -- treat both sides the same, so the concept is less applicable there.

From the logical perspective, I'm using it to mean the query that defines the population.  An important similarity is that for a left/right outer join, both definitions are, in practice, the same.  The optimizer would typically choose the first table in a `left join` as the "driver", because it defines the output rows.

Comment: "What is a driving table" http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:192812348072 You use it in a slightly different context. +1 for the added explanation.

Comment: @JanDoggen . . . I tried to explain what I mean this in the edited comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to achieve is a a count grouped by `id` and `item`, why don't you just :

```
SELECT ID, Item, COUNT(1)
FROM Table 1
GROUP BY ID, Item
```

It's as simple as that!

Comment: I am also interested in the cases where the count is 0 though

Comment: That is not what he wants, look at the 0's in the CNT column: items 8 and 34 appear for at least one other ID than 1, for ID=1 their count = 0

Answer (score -2):

The speed problem from your query is likely "distinct", which functionally selects all the data, sorts and then eliminiates duplicates before returning the results. "Distinct" is an expensive function.