# I need some help to re-write my query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have this table:

```
ID         ITEM
-----------------
0001        345
0001        345
0001        120
0002        567
0002        034
0002        567
0003        567
0004        533
0004        008
......
```

and in order to get this result:

```
ID  ITEM    CNT
1   008      0
1   034      0
1   120      1
1   345      2
1   533      0
1   567      0
2   008      0
2   034      1
...
```

CNT are the occurrences of each item for every distinct ID

I run this query:

```
select driver.id, driver.item, coalesce(count(t1.id), 0)
from (select id.id, item.item
      from (select distinct id from Table1) id cross join
           (select distinct item from Table1) item
     ) driver left outer join
     Table1 t1
     on driver.id = t1.id and driver.item = t1.item
group by driver.id, driver.item;
```

This query is taking forever and still hasn't finished after a day..
This is the results of the EXPLAIN:

[image: Explain]

idx_id and idx_code are the indexes for ID and ITEM

Can you give me some hints on how to improve my query so it can run faster and hopefully finish? Thanks

Comment: The result doesn't quite explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count query is taking too long - over 24 hours have passed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996652/count-query-is-taking-too-long-over-24-hours-have-passed)

Comment: CNT are the occurrences of each item for every distinct ID

Comment: I don't understand why I got so many down-votes..This is a different question from my previous one...Well thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is: **Divide and conquer**. Create temp tables for the intermediate steps, index them, and then use them to get your final result.

Specifically:

```
-- The deduplicated item list
drop table if exists temp_items;
create temporary table temp_items
    select distinct item from Table1;
alter table temp_items
    add primary key (item);

-- The deduplicated id list
drop table if exists temp_ids;
create temporary table temp_ids
    select distinct id from Table1;
alter table temp_ids
    add primary key (id);

-- The cross join
drop table if exist temp_ids_items
create temporary table temp_ids_items
    select id, item
    from temp_ids, temp_items;
-- Important: Index the cross join
alter table temp_ids_items
    add index idx_id(id),
    add index idx_item(item); -- Optionally: add unique index idx_dedup(id, item)
```

Now you can use this temp table to get what you need:

```
select 
    a.id, a.item, coalesce(count(t1.id), 0)
from 
    temp_ids_items as a
    left join Table1 as t1 on (a.id = t1.id and a.item=t1.item)
group by
    a.id, a.item;
```

I think you don't need the `coalesce()` function (if you count `null` values, the result is zero), but it is just an opinion.

Remember: Temp tables are visible only to the connection that creates them, and they are eliminated when the connection is closed. I think it may be useful to put all above process in a stored procedure.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question..I'm going to try this out